# Find position of specific column pattern

Tags: awk

After some processing I ended up with a file like this one:

```
ALA 251
VAL 252
TYR 253
LYS 254
SER 255
ALA 256
ALA 257
MET 258
LEU 259
ASP 260
MET 261
THR 262
GLY 263
ALA 264
GLY 265
TYR 266
VAL 267
TRP 268
```

Let's call the first column "res" and the second "num".
Please note that "res" is always composed of 3 letters, and "num" going from 1 to 4 numbers.

I am looking for a way to extract the position (value of column "num") corresponding to the first "res" of the exact column pattern composed of four successive "res" like this one:

```
TYR
LYS
SER
ALA
```

In this case, according to the file and the indicated pattern, the output should then be:

```
253
```

I made several attemps with awk. It seems it should be doable but my skills aren't sufficient for the moment. I would be very gratefull if any brilliant user has a proposition for this.

Comment: Not an answer, but a suggestion: this format is hard to read. I bet that we could give you much better answers if you asked on our sister site, [bioinformatics.se] but ask about your actual input data, before you format it in this way. Presumably, you have a protein fasta file at some point and it would almost certainly be much simpler to find the pattern there.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the advise. You're right it is protein, but extracted from structural pdb file.

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding [terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon)’s [excellent suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542637/find-position-of-specific-column-pattern#comment1006153_542637), the following AWK script does the job:

```
$1 == "TYR" { seq = $1; start = $2; next }
($1 == "LYS" && seq == "TYR") || ($1 == "SER" && seq == "LYS") { seq = $1; next }
$1 == "ALA" && seq == "SER" { print start }
{ seq = "" }
```

This looks for `TYR`, and remembers the start position; it also matches `TYR`, `LYS`, `SER` in the correct sequence, noting the previous item in the sequence in `seq` at every stage. Non-matching lines cause the sequence to be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Sliding window with `sed`:

*parse.sed*

```
# Establish the sliding window
1N
2N

# Maintain the sliding window
N

# Match the desired pattern to the current window
/^TYR \(.*\)\nLYS .*\nSER .*\nALA .*$/ { 
  h;                           # Save the window in hold space
  s//\1/p;                     # Extract desired output
  x;                           # Re-establish window
}

# Maintain the sliding window
D
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -nf parse.sed infile
```

Output:

```
253
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks, it is working great. I definitely should have a better look of how sed is working.

Answer (score 0):

Same approach as in [Stephen Kitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542639/332764), but without additional `seq` variable. Instead the sequential "number" is used to determine if the current line belongs to the set we're looking for.

```
awk '{
  if ($1=="TYR") {
    i=$2 # remember index
  }
  else if (i!=0) { 
    if ($2==i+1 && $1=="LYS" || $2==i+2 && $1=="SER" || $2==i+3 && $1=="ALA") {
      if ($2==i+3) { # are we there yet?
        print i; exit
      }
    }
    else {
      i=0 # nope, reset index
    }
  }
}' file
```

(Unneeded curly braces and indentation left for readability)

Comment: That's working great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Transpose your data and pattern and the task becomes easier, e.g.:

```
# Determine offset to pattern
offset=$(cut -d' ' -f1 infile | paste -s | grep -ob "$(paste -s patternfile)" | cut -d: -f1)

# Adjust for field length
reslength=3
(( offset = offset % reslength + 1 ))

# Extract desired number
awk -v offset=$offset 'NR==offset { print $2 }' infile
```

Output:

```
253
```

Note that this solution assumes that there is only one match.

Comment: Launching the script I got : "Illegal variable name." I am working on it. Thanks a lot for the proposition and comment. I calculated that using a 4 res window renders highly improbable than two matches appear in the any "infiles" I am working with. Best :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a sliding window:

*parse.awk*

```c
# Split the pattern into the `p` array and remember how many there are in `n`
BEGIN { n = split(pat, p, "\n") }

# Collect n lines into the `A` array
NR <= n { A[NR] = $0; next }

# Maintain the sliding window after n lines
NR  > n {
  for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
    A[i-1] = A[i]
  A[n] = $0
}

# Test if the current window contains the pattern
{
  hit = 1
  for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    split(A[i], x)
    if(x[1] != p[i]) {
      hit = 0
      break
    }
  }

  # If the window matches print the second column
  if(hit) {
    split(A[1], x)
    print x[2]
  }
}
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -v pat="$(< patternfile)" -f parse.awk infile
```

Output:

```
253
```

Comment: Wow... very elegant. I never saw the usage of  : " awk -v pat="$(< variable)"

Comment: In particular < . I had troubles to make the script work to begin with, getting "Illegal variable name." But it was simply solved switching to bash. Many thanks!

Comment: @Siondubois: Sorry, that is a bashism.  In most shells you can get away with `"$(cat patternfile)"